# tcblisting box with minted doesn't support comments

Tags: tcolorbox, minted

I noticed that for some tcblisting boxes, the code doesn't show correctly.

[image]

At first, I thought it was something with the preamble since it had occurred another time with another file, but after some testing, it appears that it has to do with multiline comments (`"""comment"""` in Python) - single line comments seem to work fine and regular code snippets without comments work perfectly in the boxes. Here is the code for the tcblisting boxes as well as the output.

Code for `tcbdefinition` and `tcbexample`:

```
    % code def
    \newtcblisting[auto counter, number within=section, list inside=definitionlist]{tcbdefinition}[2][]{%
        colback=red!5, colbacktitle=red!20, coltitle=black,
        frame hidden, arc=2pt, titlerule=0pt, toptitle=2pt, bottomtitle=2pt,
        fonttitle=\bfseries, breakable, enhanced, parbox=false,
        segmentation style={solid, draw=red!20, line width=1pt},
        comment and listing,
        title=Definition~\thetcbcounter,
        comment={#2},#1
    }
    % code example
    \newtcblisting[auto counter, number within=section, list inside=examplelist]{tcbexample}[2][]{%
    colback=gray!5, colbacktitle=gray!40, coltitle=black,
    frame hidden, arc=2pt, titlerule=0pt, toptitle=2pt, bottomtitle=2pt,
    fonttitle=\bfseries, breakable, enhanced, parbox=false,
    segmentation style={solid, draw=gray!20, line width=1pt},
    comment and listing,
    title=Example~\thetcbcounter,
    comment={#2},#1
    }

% generate Name
    \pgfkeysifdefined{/tcb/name}{\fail}{
    \tcbset{
    name/.style={after title={: #1}}}
    }
```

Input Code:

```
Here is a cool Python function:
\begin{minted}{python}
def a_function(n):
    """A test function"""
    while n > 0:
        print("Test") # prints Test
    return "Done"
\end{minted}

\begin{tcbdefinition}[name = Defining a Cool Python Function, minted language = python]{Here is a cool Python function: \mintinline{text}{code}
}
def a_function(n):
    """a comment"""
    while n > 0:
        print("Test")
    return "Done"
\end{tcbdefinition}

\begin{tcbexample}[name = Defining a Cool Python Function, minted language = python]{
Here is a cool Python function: \mintinline{text}{code}
}
def a_function(n):
    # a comment
    while n > 0:
        print("Test")
    return "Done"
\end{tcbexample}
```

[image]

If anyone knows how to get minted/tcblisting to stop getting irritated at my multiline comments, that would be nice. Thanks!

Comment: Apart from the undefined key `/tcb/name` error, I cannot reproduce your problem. Can you provide a complete example instead of code snippets?

Comment: Sorry, that was my bad. I forgot to add the `/tcb/name` code. Once edited it should work properly.

Comment: A complete example which starts with `\documentclass`, ends with `\end{document}`, and can reproduce the problem on you side is required, because  I cannot reproduce your problem on a latest texlive 2021. You OS and version of `minted` and `tcolorbox` may be helpful as well.

Comment: Will add those once I am free. However, I looked into the bug a bit more recently and it seems to be more of a heisenbug - in some cases it does not compile correctly but in other cases the same exact code in minted will display this issue, which makes it quite tricky.

Additionally, how do you get the version of minted and tcolorbox? Thanks!

Comment: Put `\listfiles` in preamble then you can find versions near the end of log.